# align text in text widget vertically

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, tkinter, grid

I am using tkinter's grid geometry manager to create a 'table' of text, entry and label widgets.
The text widgets (colored blue) are used to display the name of the variable (e.g. 'theta_air') to be input by the user into the according entry widget, while the label widget displays the appropriate unit (e.g. '°C').

I have already aligned the entry and the label widget vertically. As indicated by the blue background of the text widget, the text widgets theirselves are aligned, properly. However, I am not able to align the text of the text widget vertically. Or, in other words, the baseline of the text widget is not aligned to the baseline of the entry or the label widget.

How can I align the text of the text widget vertically or achieve a similar optical behaviour?
Both a screenshot and the according code snippet (not working standalone) is shown below.

[image: Screenshot]

```
self.parameternames = [
    {'name': 'a', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'b', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'c', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'd', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'e', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'f', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'g', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'h', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'i', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'j', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'k', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'l', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'm', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'n', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.},
    {'name': 'o', 'unit': '\u00b0C', 'coords': (0, 0), 'default': 0.}]

for i, subdict in enumerate(self.parameternames):
    r = i % 4
    c = (i // 4) * 3
    self.lowerframe.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
    self.lowerframe.grid_columnconfigure(c+2, weight=1)
    t = Text(self.lowerframe, width=5, height=2, background='#336699', font=('', 12))
    t.tag_configure('subscript', offset=-4, font=('', 10))
    t.tag_configure('justify_right', justify='right')
    t.insert('insert', '\u03d1', 'justify_right', 'air', 'subscript')
    t.configure(state='disabled')
    t.grid(row=r, column=c, pady=5, padx=0, sticky='NSE')
    Label(self.lowerframe, text=subdict['unit'], anchor=W).grid(row=r, column=c+2, pady=5, padx=0, sticky='W')
    subdict['var_table'] = StringVar()
    entry_table = Entry(self.lowerframe, width=10, justify='right', textvariable=subdict['var_table'])
    entry_table.grid(row=r, column=c+1, pady=5, padx=0, sticky='EW')
    subdict['pname_table'] = str(entry_table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I used `height=1` which seemed to cut of the subscripted text so I tried using `height=2`. To proof whether the index/subsrcipt is cut off, I used another index like `dryer` containing the 'y' which is below the index' baseline.

However, if using `height=1` the subscript is not cut off at all as you can see from the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

The adapted line of code is as follows:

```
t = Text(self.lowerframe, width=5, height=1, background='#336699', font=('', 12))
```